# django south fresh install --> error: unknown command 'schemamigration'

Tags: django, django-south

## short story

I run `./manage.py schemamigration junk_app --initial` on a completely fresh django project right after freshly installing South ( http://south.aeracode.org/ ), and I get the following error:

```
Unknown command: 'schemamigration'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

EDIT: I have version .7 (south/**init.py** has **version** = ".07")

## long story

Below is almost a literal copy/paste of what just happened:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-django-south
$ django-admin.py startproject junk_proj
$ cd junk_proj
$ ./managy.py startapp junk_app
$ vim settings.py #add 'south' to INSTALLED_APPS
```

.

```
$ cat settings.py
# Django settings for junk_proj project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

import os
CWD = os.getcwd()
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'           # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = CWD+'/db'             # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = ''             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'vgtm!i0*(qn$8m9&0u_)#(5yh(kt8%+4dlwfum%xtt-$1ge+ld'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'junk_proj.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'south',
    'junk_app',
)
```

.

```
$ ./managy.py syncdb
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table south_migrationhistory

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (leave blank to use 'foo'): admin
E-mail address: admin@example.com
Password:
Password (again):
Superuser created successfully.
Installing index for auth.Permission model
Installing index for auth.Message model

synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > south
 > junk_app

Not synced (use migrations):
 -
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
$
$./manage.py schemamigration junk_app --initial
Unknown command 'schemamigration'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage
$
```

Comment: Which version of South did you download? `schemamigration` didn't appear in earlier versions. What do you get when you type `./manage.py` with no args?

Comment: `Available subcommands:
  cleanup
  compilemessages
  convert_to_south
  createcachetable
  createsuperuser
  dbshell
  diffsettings
  dumpdata
  flush
  inspectdb
  loaddata
  makemessages
  migrate
  reset
  runfcgi
  runserver
  shell
  sql
  sqlall
  sqlclear
  sqlcustom
  sqlflush
  sqlindexes
  sqlinitialdata
  sqlreset
  sqlsequencereset
  startapp
  startmigration
  syncdb
  test
  testserver
  validate
`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `apt-get` for this sort of thing. Nothing in your OS depends on South so there's no reason to tie yourself to whichever old version was packaged for your OS. Use `pip` instead.

Comment: I have the same problem, running the latest version of south... doesn't seem like it's installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably using some old South version, 0.6.x or even 0.5.x. If you type that "./manage.py help" you should see `startmigration` (iirc) on the list of available commands.

Comment: Also, in 0.7 `startmigration` was split into `schemamigration` and `datamigration`.  There was no real equivalent for `datamigration` in earlier versions; you had to do `startmigration` and then replace the migration code yourself.

Comment: How do I tell what version of South I have? I only see startmigration option when I type ./manage.py help, but that makes no sense because I just installed via apt-get on an Ubuntu 10 machine (I've never edited sources file). How could I have an outdated version of South, and how do I officially find the version I have?

Comment: startmigration worked, btw, but I still would like to know the version I'm usging.

Comment: To see the version you're using, `import south` in the interpreter and then print `south.__version__`.

Comment: You can also check the version in south/__init__.py

Comment: @Thr4wn: Maybe you have two South's installed (one local, inside project, and one using apt-get) and the older one is prevailing, possibly because it's parent folder is placed earlier on Python path ?

Answer (score 35):

You probably haven't added 'south' into the list of INSTALLED_APPS of your settings.py file.

Here's a quote from http://south.aeracode.org/docs/installation.html#installation-configure

> Now you’ve installed South system-wide, you’ll need to configure
>   Django to use it. Doing so is simple; just edit your settings.py and
>   add 'south' to the end of INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> If Django doesn’t seem to pick this up, check that you’re not
>   overriding INSTALLED_APPS elsewhere, and that you can run import south
>   from inside ./manage.py shell with no errors.
>
> Once South is added in, you’ll need to run ./manage.py syncdb to make
>   the South migration-tracking tables (South doesn’t use migrations for
>   its own models, for various reasons).

Comment: Adding 'south' into the list of INSTALLED_APPS saved my day :-) Thank you.

Comment: I added `'south',` to the end of my INSTALLED_APPS and it still is not recognized.  Any ideas?  I'm using virtualenv on Windows 7.

Comment: This part is muy importante!!! `If Django doesn’t seem to pick this up, check that you’re not overriding INSTALLED_APPS elsewhere, and that you can run import south from inside ./manage.py shell with no errors.`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the Ubuntu package, use `easy_install` or `pip` to install South.  This will ensure you have the most recent version.

Answer (score 3):

I think this problem can be very elusive. I spent considerable time and I then figured out that I was overriding `INSTALLED_APPS` for some testing. Doh! So this is key. Be sure to add `south` at the end of your `INSTALLED_APPS` and if you override it, check that too.

Answer (score 2):

check, which settings.py file you use:

```
./manage.py shell
import settings
settings.__file__
```

you may see in manage.py, which settings file Django use by defaul:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
```

or you may use:

```
 $./manage.py schemamigration junk_app --settings=settings --initial
```

instead of:

```
 $./manage.py schemamigration junk_app --initial
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your settings in a settings folder, make sure you use a **.** and not **/** in the path.
Example: `./manage.py schemamigration secretballot --initial --settings=settings.jacob`